# Illegal import of slf4j in Sonar

Tags: java, slf4j, sonarqube, importerror

I have a lot of Severity - **Major** issues in Sonar that are caused by the "**Illegal Import**" rule.

Most of them are because of the following lines:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
```

and

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem without changing the Sonar profile? (I don't have access to it)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if this rule is enabled, it means that you should not use these imports in your code.

So either you consider these issues as false positives (in which case you should mark them as such), or these are real issues that you need to fix - e.g by using your project's recommended logging framework instead of SLF4J.

If you don't have access to the quality profile settings, maybe you can suggest to the profile's owner to add an extended description on this rule, in order to provide insights on ways to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Place // NOSONAR comment at the end of every line this problem occurs. Sonar will skip it